# Magento category page layout change is not reflecting in frontend

Tags: magento, layout

I'm trying to give one column page layout for all categories, by going to `catalog --> Manage categories --> (Required category) --> custom design --> Page layout --> (Selected 1 column from dropdown)`

But in my frontend i'm getting that page with right sidebar. While enabling template path hints i found the temlate is 2column-right.phtml

Did anyone gone through this problem ?
please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are doing it under correct scope (Store/Website/Store View)?

Comment: There's no such option available while creating a category ?

Comment: Not true. At "Manage Categories" page there's a "Choose Store View:" drop down at the top-left and "Page Layout" can be different for any store view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you have cleared your cache? 
Do you have any other caches enabled?

Comment: yes i deleted manually too.. but still coming the same.. I tried using custom layout by adding <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
Now it's working but top menu's are vanishing...

Comment: Have you set the Page layout back to default on the category?

Comment: No i'm breaking my head to do this !! Did  you have any idea to do this ?